# how do i empirically estimate variance of conditional normal distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, variance, simulation

I've tried searching for this, but maybe I'm not using the correct search strings. suppose I have joint distribution $P(X_1,X_2)$ over 2 continuous random variables $X_1,X_2$ that I can sample from. What is the correct algorithm to estimate the variance of $P(X_2|X_1)$ ?

if the conditioning variable was discrete, I could simply slice at $X_1 = x_1$ and calculate the variance of the $X_2$ that fall into this slice. the main issue is with the continuous variables. Do I use a smooth bin, where say I wanted $P(X_2|X_1 = 1)$ I would  take samples around $X_1 = 1$ weighted by some kernel?

Would appreciate some canonical resource for this, feel I am reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Are $X_1,X_2$ jointly Gaussian?

Comment: You may need some assumptions, such as the conditional variance being constant, or in some sense changing slowly and smoothly with $X_1$.

Comment: @d.k.o. so would an empirical ( i.e. by simulation) method require such a guarantee? say  X1 and X2 are indeed jointly gaussian. In that case what would be an appropriate method?

Comment: @Henry interesting, so is there a method available if the variance changes smoothly and slowly with X1?also when you say smooth+slow do you mean in the theoretical sense that the joint probability of X1 and X2 is a n-differentiable function (i.e. no abrupt ups and downs), or do you mean some practical notion of slow?

Comment: You are likely to end up in some sense regressing $X_2$ on $X_1$ and then looking at the variance of the residuals near $X_1=1$, and you would like that to be a sensible thing to do.  (If you think the conditional variance is constant then not just near $X_1=1$)

Comment: No. However, the title mentions "conditional normal distribution".

Comment: @d.k.o. right, we can assume joint gaussian nature.

Comment: In this case you just need to estimate the correlation between $X_1$ and $X_2$ and the variance of $X_2$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case_2

Comment: @d.k.o. ah, ok so just get the unconditional correlation between $X_1$ , $X_2$, unconditional variance of $X_2$ and plug it into the formula.  sounds appropriate. if you post it as an answer I'll accept it for future readers.

Comment: Look at [this paper](http://stats.lse.ac.uk/q.yao/qyao.links/paper/bka98.pdf) for a more general case. BTW, you may answer your own question.